# Calcular el cuadrado de los primeros 50 numeros enteros y mostrarlo como una tabla

Tags: java, array

Se deben utilizar arrays, hasta ahorita solo he logrado conseguir mostrar 50 numeros iguales, se deben de mostrar como una tabla los primeros 50 numeros enteros naturales del 1 al 50

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class cuadrado50numeros {
public static void main (String[]args){
 Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
int []numeros;
int []numeroscuadrados;
int n=2,i,j,g=50,h=5;
System.out.println("imprime los primeros 50 numeros enteros");
numeros=new int[g];

for (i=0;i<g;i++){
          for (j=0;j<=h;j++){   
              numeros[j]=h; 
              
}
}
for (i=0;i<g;i++){
      for (j=0;j<n;j++){
          System.out.print("\t"+numeros[j]);
  }
      System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
   System.out.println(i + " : " + i * i);
}
```

Se construye un **ciclo for** desde **1** hasta **50** y por cada iteración se muestra el número y el cuadrado de dicho número.